# How can I programmatically delete Rows from an excel that are currently empty but have been edited once , using closed xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml, closedxml

I need to delete empty rows from my excel using closed XML. These rows previously had some data but are now empty. I have tried using row.IsEmpty() but it does not delete any rows at all. Below is what I have tried so far:

```
using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(destinationPath))
{
    int worksheetCount = workBook.Worksheets.Count;
    for(int worksheetIndex = 1; worksheetIndex <= worksheetCount; worksheetIndex++)
    {
        //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
        IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

        int rowCount = workSheet.RowsUsed().Count();

        //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
        foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.RowsUsed())
        {
            if (row.IsEmpty())
            {
                row.Delete();
            }
        } 

        workBook.Save();
        int rowCountNew = workSheet.RowsUsed().Count();
```

My rowCount and rowCountNew have the same values when actually they should be different. Also,even though I have empty rows in the excel my if condition continues to remain false and hence never hits row.delete(). Hope my question makes sense.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Hi, Is it ok for you to try to delete any entire row. Usually excel has the option of shifting cells up, down , left or right. Kindly try the row.delete() function without conditions to see how the deletion willl be peforming.

Comment: hi @Gnyasha I am not sure how removing the condition would help.However, I did try that and it just deletes all the rows. But I need to delete only the rows which are empty. IsEmpty() doesn't detect the empty rows because all those rows had some data previously.. any idea how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Your core issue is to find out why `row.IsEmpty()` returns false. For the parameterless `.IsEmpty()` overload, ClosedXML uses the `XLCellsUsedOptions.AllContents` value to determine whether cells are empty. This means that if a cell contains values or comments, it is considered non-empty. My guess is that you forgot to clear some comments.

Comment: Hi Francois , I have checked the excel properly only 6 rows have data and there were some 10 rows which previously had data but now are empty , so my row count returns count as 16 instead of 6, if RowsUsed().Count() would have been returning 6 I would not need to use that condition , but that's not what is happening.

Comment: Try to identify the exact `IXLCell` in the row that return `.IsEmpty() == false` .

Answer (score 0):

Using closed XML library we can iterate through each workbook and delete a given row based on the row number

```
     string srcFile ="srcfile.xlsx"; 
     string dstFile = "destnation file.xlsx";
     using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(srcFile))
        {
            foreach (var item in wb.Worksheets)
            {
                item.Row(2).Delete();
            }

            wb.SaveAs(dstFile);
        }
```